# Illuminate\Routing\Exceptions\UrlGenerationException: Missing required parameters for

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, laravel-6.2

I'm using Laravel 6.2. I have a named route

```
Route::get('/dummy/{id}', 'Api\V1\DummyDataController@show')->name('dummy_data_show');
```

I cannot write the test for it, I get the error `Illuminate\Routing\Exceptions\UrlGenerationException: Missing required parameters for [Route: dummy_data_show] [URI: api/v1/dummy/{id}].`

These are my attempts (only relevant code):

```
$request = $this->withHeaders(
            [
                'Accept' => 'application/json',
                'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$token,
            ]
        )->json('GET',
            Route('dummy_data_show'),
            [
                'id' => 1,
            ]
        );
```

and also

```
$request = $this->withHeaders(
            [
                'Accept' => 'application/json',
                'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$token,
            ]
        )->json('GET',
            Route('dummy_data_show'),
            1
        );
```

Of course if I try with

```
$request = $this->withHeaders(
            [
                'Accept' => 'application/json',
                'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$token,
            ]
        )->json('api/v1/dummy/1');
```

I don't get the error. What is my error? Thank you!

Comment: The id is part of the URL definition, not an extra parameter, so it must be passed in the URL as part of the path.

Comment: Thank you for your answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not passing any parameters to your `route` method. The parameters should be inside the parenthesis.

Change:

```php
Route('dummy_data_show'),
[
    'id' => 1,
]
```

To:

```php
route('dummy_data_show', [
    'id' => 1,
])
```